# backbone require.js access to models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Im studying require and modular programming with backbone.

My question specifically is how can I access the models I have created in the View module as shown below from the main page, (example from the console), as is allways telling me undefined.

I understand that as its encapsulated in the view module, but is being hard to me to understand where I should create the instances of the model and collection as if I do it in init.js I get them to be undefined in the view module when i define collections or model.

If I instance them from model or collections modules I get a bunch of undefined errors

I have this init.js;

```
requirejs.config({
enforceDefine: true,
baseUrl: 'js', 

urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),

shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
},  
paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.10.2.min',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone.min',
    underscore: 'lib/underscore.min',
    text: 'lib/require/text',

    Plato: 'app/models/plato',
    Carta: 'app/collections/carta',
    MainView: 'app/views/mainView',
    mainTemplate: 'app/templates/mainTemplate.html'
}   
});

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'MainView'], function($, _, Backbone, MainView) {  
    console.log(typeof $);
    console.log(typeof _);
    console.log(typeof Backbone);   
    var mainView = new MainView;
});
```

Then I have mainView.js as:

```
define(['backbone', 'text!mainTemplate', 'Plato', 'Carta'], function(Backbone, mainTemplate, Plato, Carta) {  

var pizza = new Plato({precio:120, nombre:'pizza', foto:'n/a', ingredientes: 'harina, tomate, oregano', diabeticos:false}),
    empanada = new Plato({precio:40, nombre:'empanada', foto:'n/a', ingredientes: 'harina, carne picada', diabeticos:false}),
    lasagna = new Plato({precio:200, nombre:'lasagna', foto:'n/a', ingredientes: 'pasta, queso', diabeticos:false}),
    carta = new Carta([pizza, empanada, lasagna]),

MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    id: 'mainView',
    events: {'click td': 'clickAction'},

    collection: carta,

    template: _.template(mainTemplate, this.collection),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            console.log(item.toJSON() + item.get('nombre'));              
            this.$el.append( this.template( item.toJSON() ));          
        }, this);            

        $('#content').html(this.$el);
        return this;
    },
    clickAction: function() {
        alert(this);
    }
});
return MainView;
});
```

I also have the model and collection modules if that helps you out to help me.

My main purpose would be to be able to access them and then put a listener or an on in the elements to be able to play with the data of those models.

Sorry If I am confused and mixing concepts with the variable scope of the modules using require.js and backbone, but I have read whatever I was able to find in the internet and Im still confused.

EDIT

---

Should I create and entire module just to instantiate them and then export the values as an object??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create and entire module just to instantiate them and then
>   export the values as an object??

Yes.  That's one way to accomplish what you are looking to do:

```
define(['backbone', 'text!mainTemplate', 'Plato', 'Carta', 'carta'], 
    function(Backbone, mainTemplate, Plato, Carta, carta) {
...
});
```

Where Carta is the collection module and carta is the object that contains the data.

Comment: Tried making a module named data with a data object and all instances in it, works quite well. anyway, is this a correct approach?

Comment: Normally with a backbone collection, you would be pulling the data off the server (from an API endpoint for example).  So, you could pass the Carta collection module in, create an instance of it inside your view and call fetch() to retrieve the data.  In that case, this wouldn't be an issue.

This question is really about how to make your data object available to the AMD module.  If you paste an example of how you are trying to instantiate your data object inside the Carta collection, I can give feedback on that.  I think that would be an equally valid way of passing the data into the view.